# Why my lifts are getting stronger every week

Tags: weightlifting, strength, gym, motivation, genetics

I started deadlifting for like 1 month now, i never workout back in the gym and chest also i enjoy more doing pull ups and push ups for this muscle group. So when i started deadlifting once a week i was getting surprised bc every week my deadlifts are getting stronger and stronger, like the first time tryed i was feeling like i have very weak lower back and some muscle imbalance there so it was difficult for me even to deadlift some 40kg the first day now it has been a month from now and i have reached like 120 kg for 5 reps now the last week i couldnt do more than than 1 rep it was a pr for me. Does it mean i have good genetics?

I am 20 years old 6 feet 75kg.

Answer (score 7):

#### It means you’re new to deadlifting.

It is not at all unusual to see remarkable strength gains in the first few months of regularly training a *new* lift. My own experience was similar to yours: when I first started deadlifting, my 1RM went from 40kg to 140kg in six weeks. Then it took six months to go from 140kg to 180kg. Then it took another six months to go from 180kg to 200kg. The. It took a year to go from 200kg to 220kg. Things seem to be on track for me to hit 230kg by the end of this training block, and it’s been *eighteen months* since I hit 220kg. The first few months of training a lift is almost entirely just adapting to the movement - training your brain to lift the weight. But once you’ve got that worked out, muscle mass then becomes the primary limiting factor in strength, and it is much slower to gain mass than it is to just learn the movement.